# equalize div height on container row

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, height

I have tried numerous things (css & js) and can't get some boxs to have equal heights on the following site:

http://www.ancoris.com

The boxes I'm talking about start at the "**Ancoris Success Stories**" (the orange box) and the 2 to the right.

The area I'm talking about is below (I haven't included all code, just the container & 3 div's I need to equalise):

```
<div id="below-content" class="row-fluid">
   <div class="moduletable first orangebox h3 span4">
   <div class="moduletable blueboxonly span4">
   <div class="moduletable orangebox h3 span4">
</div>
```

Preferably I want to do this with CSS if possible - but just can't get it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set all div height to the height of a div, which has maximum height.

```
var maxHeight = 0;

var divs = jQuery("#below-content .moduletable");

jQuery.each(divs, function(){
    var height = jQuery(this).height();
    if(maxHeight<height)
        maxHeight = height;

});
divs.height(maxHeight);
```

Comment: hasn't worked for me... placing in both my head or body, wrapped with <script type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: I edited my answer, replace $ to jQuery, as you are using jQuery.noConflict() there.

Comment: @user991830, the timing of this method is important as the dynamic content may not be rendered yet. What you can do in that case is to have this Answer fired every time new content is added to the boxes. **+1** for a great answer! Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

For this you can use **display:table** property for this. Write like this:

```
#below-content{
 display:table;
}
.moduletable{
 display:table-cell;
}
```

*Note: `display:table` for till IE8 & above*

Comment: I tried that on tthat spefic div, liike this... but it messes up the row. tried in firebug. 
#below-content{
 display:table;
}
div#below-content.row-fluid div.moduletable{
 display:table-cell !important;
}

Answer (score 1):

Make a new **CSS Style Rule** to have a minimum height requirement for an existing CSS Selector seen in this [**file**](http://www.ancoris.com/templates/ancoris/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css) at **line 15**.

Based on the current CSS in use, the center box is locked in at `height:256px` with `padding:9px` applied to the top and bottom of this element. That said, the total minimum height is `274px` (9 + 256 + 9).

```
.row-fluid .span4{
  min-height: 274px;
}
```

The above CSS Selector dictates the minimum height for the whole row of boxes.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

---

**Status Update:**

Because the content in the orange and blue boxes **has dynamic content**, you can actually define any ***desired*** `min-height` for the webpage layout requirements. The previous `274px` was based on the blue box content at that time.

Note if content ever exceeds this set threshold you will once again have uneven boxes.

The solution is to discover what's the **actual** minimum height required. That's achieved by looking at each orange box and the blue box to know what the **maximum item count is** along with the **maximum item height** to realize the final vertical height needed.

Then, when **all boxes** are showing *dynamic data* at ***100% capacity*** or values less than this, everything still will be **equalized** in height.

Taking that **layout-management** one step further, you can do the same for the boxes on the *right side* so the ***Blog Box*** bottom lines with the other bottoms of that row.

Answer (score 0):

What about tables? It seems people are trying to make div behave like tables using css rules but what about having a proper table added to render your blocks?

I know, tables are bad if not used correctly. "Correctly" here means you should not use tables to render stuff that don't need tables to be rendered pretty much... I get that from many articles: tables are not deprecated, just to be used with care.
The thing here is that you don't really have much of a choice! CSS is too flaky to make it happen and Javascript seems to me like a hammer to kill a fly.

I advise you to give it a go with tables and see how it goes. And let us know of course.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```html
function equalHeight(group) {
    jQuery(group).css("height", "auto");

    eqheight = 0;
    group.each(function () {
        thisHeight = jQuery(this).height();
        if (thisHeight > eqheight) {
            eqheight = thisHeight;
        }
    });
    group.height(eqheight);
}
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    equalHeight(jQuery(".moduletable"));
});
jQuery(window).resize(function () {
    equalHeight(jQuery(".moduletable"));
});
```

```js
function equalHeight(group) {
    jQuery(group).css("height", "auto");

    eqheight = 0;
    group.each(function () {
        thisHeight = jQuery(this).height();
        if (thisHeight > eqheight) {
            eqheight = thisHeight;
        }
    });
    group.height(eqheight);
}
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    equalHeight(jQuery(".moduletable"));
});
jQuery(window).resize(function () {
    equalHeight(jQuery(".moduletable"));
});
```

```css
.blueboxonly{
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.orangebox{
  background-color: orange;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="below-content" class="row-fluid">
   <div class="moduletable first orangebox h3 span4"> 01 div</div>
   <div class="moduletable blueboxonly span4"> 02 div<br/>02 div</div>
   <div class="moduletable orangebox h3 span4"> 03 div<br/>03 div<br/>03 div</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function equalHeight(group) {
    jQuery(group).css("height", "auto");

    eqheight = 0;
    group.each(function () {
        thisHeight = jQuery(this).height();
        if (thisHeight > eqheight) {
            eqheight = thisHeight;
        }
    });
    group.height(eqheight);
}
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    equalHeight(jQuery(".moduletable"));
});
jQuery(window).resize(function () {
    equalHeight(jQuery(".moduletable"));
});
```

```css
.blueboxonly{
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.orangebox{
  background-color: orange;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="below-content" class="row-fluid">
   <div class="moduletable first orangebox h3 span4"> 01 div</div>
   <div class="moduletable blueboxonly span4"> 02 div<br/>02 div</div>
   <div class="moduletable orangebox h3 span4"> 03 div<br/>03 div<br/>03 div</div>
</div>
```